# Identification Topology (Mendelson's 'Introduction to Topology', page 103)

Tags: general-topology, relations, quotient-spaces

Let $f: (X, \sigma) \rightarrow (Y, \tau)$ be continuous and let $a \sim b$ if $f(a) = f(b)$. Noting $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, let $\pi(x)$ map $x$ to its equivalence class. Noting $\pi: X \rightarrow X/\sim$ is onto, give $X/\sim$ the identification topology $\upsilon$ determined by $\pi$. Since $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ implies $f(a) = f(b)$, $f$ induces a continuous function $g: X/\sim\, \rightarrow Y$ such that $f = g\pi$ (see Theorem 8.2, Chapter 3 of Mendelson's *Introduction to Topology*). We have

$g(\pi(a)) = g(\pi(b)) \Rightarrow f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow \pi(a) = \pi(b)$,

and so $g$ is one-to-one. Since $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(\tau) \subset \upsilon$.

**Confusion:**

According to Mendelson's *Introduction to Topology* (page 103), since $g$ is one-to-one, $g^{-1}(\tau) \subset \upsilon$ is equivalent to $\tau \subset g(\upsilon)$, and therefore, since $\tau$ is any topology on $Y$, the topology 'carried over' to $Y$ by $g$ is the weakest topology such that $f$ is continuous.

It is not clear to me that either of these statements make sense unless $g$ is onto. However, even if $g$ is onto, for any $T \in \tau$, $g^{-1}(T)$ is open, and so the identification topology on $Y$ determined by $g$ contains $T$. Therefore this identification topology ought to be strongest topology on $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous. Here I am assuming that the topology 'carried over' to $Y$ by $g$ is the identification topology.

I am already a bit suspicious since Mendelson never specified that $f$ must be continuous in order to induce $g$ (I added this requirement myself).

**Questions:**

1. Is it correct that $g^{-1}(\tau) \subset \upsilon \iff \tau \subset g(\upsilon)$?
2. Am I correct in assuming that the topology 'carried over' to $Y$ by $g$ is the identification topology?
3. Is the topology 'carried over' to $Y$ by $g$ is the weakest topology such that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: As for the first point, it is not correct if you don't assume that $f$ is onto.

Comment: What do you mean by the topology carried over on to Y by g? As compared to $\tau$?

Comment: @user254665 I think by 'carried over' on to $Y$ Mendelson is talking about the identification topology on $Y$ determined by $g$ (see question 2), that is, $O$ is defined to be open in $Y$ if $g^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X/\sim$.